# jQuery submit form on success

Tags: jquery, forms

I am calling a function of third party API in a button click event.

See below, tp.callFunction which is in button click, only on success I want to store res.myNum in a hidden field and submit the form.

The part where I am confused is where to write or extend (.success(functionOne)) so that I can have a code for form submit.

```
$('[button1]').on('click', function () {
    var getdatafrom = {
        param1: $('input:text').val()
    };

    tp.callFunction(getdatafrom)
    .success(functionOne)
    .error(functionFail);
    return false;
});

function functionOne(res) {
    alert("Sample: " + res.myNum);
};

function functionFail(res) {
    alert("Error: " + res.errormessage);
};
```

I know we can do this in .ajax post like below

```
$.ajax({ 
        data: { 'field1' : email  },
        type: 'GET', 
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'url.php',
        beforeSend : function(){   },
        success: function(answer){   
            if(answer.error === false){
                   $('#greatForm').attr('validated',true);
                   $('#greatForm').submit();
            } 
            if(answer.error === true){
                //display the errors
            }
        }
     });
```

Comment: If you know how to do it in an anonymous function, wouldn't it be exactly the same in the named function ?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to only store the value and submit the form in success function,
it should be like below,

```
function functionOne(res) {
    $('#idOfYourHiddenField').val(res.myNum);
    $('#greatForm').submit();
};
```

I am assuimg that functionOne function is being called properly after your third party api success.